# Number of different arrays which can be obtained from a given array by applying the following operation M times.

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:** Number of different arrays which can be obtained from a given array by applying the following operation M times.
**Operation:** Pick an element and multiply it by -1
**Constraint** $1 <= no.of elements,M <= 10^5$ and each element $-10^6 <= A_i <= 10^6$
 
**Example:** $A=[1,2,1] M=2$;
The elements can be picked as follows $(1,1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)$
Giving the result $[1, 2, 1]
[-1, -2, 1]
[-1, 2, -1]
[1, -2, -1]$ respectively. Hence **4** different arrays. 
What kind of algorithm can i come up with to compute the no. of different arrays?

Comment: the last constraint you can remove it, it doesnt make benefit for a mathematical question, may be that is useful for a CS question

Comment: oh, i just added it so that it indicates that the elements of the given array may be 0 or negative too.

Comment: Do not answer this question.  It is from a live competition  https://www.codechef.com/JUNE16/problems/CHEFARK

Comment: i made a partial answer to this, will uncover it back once this contest ends.

Answer (score 0):

- N is the number of non-nil elemnts, the number of solutions is:

$\begin{eqnarray}
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    N \ (M\ is\ odd)\\ 
    1 \ \ \ (instead)\\ \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{eqnarray}$
+
$\binom{N}{2}(M\mod2+1)$
+
$\binom{N}{3}(\sum_{i=Mmod2,step=2}^{M/2})\binom{3}{i}$
+....

**Notes:**

- Be careful at the end of this sequence because the `sum` part will hence reduce with lower N's where i havent considered this important point
- You can imagine this as a binary string, for any combination taken from non-nil sub-elemnts N, the amount of negating a particular element can lead to not much than either changing its sign or not, so 1 for changed 0 else, for an even operations on N elements = $0000...{N}...0000$ this changes the sign of even elements only: $1100000..$ or $010010000...$ or $01010011000...$ etc, so the amount of posibilities are a sum from 2 to M stepped by i=2, chosen indisticntly from N, where for odd M, it starts from 1 through steps of i=2, as $10000...$,$1011011...$ etc.

Comment: Note:  This problem is from a live competion https://www.codechef.com/JUNE16/problems/CHEFARK  You might want to take down your answer until the contest ends.

Comment: @lulu is this why noone answered it ?

Comment: Possibly...the policy of the site is not to answer problems from live competitions, in order to respect the integrity of the contest.  By posting the problem here without citing the contest, the OP is trying to cheat.  Happens a lot.  Just last week I answered a question in full only to find out later in the day that it was a competition question.